# is there a listenable python os event when there is memory pressure

Tags: python, memory, out-of-memory, nsnotificationcenter

I want to get a notification when there is memory pressure in the system and release caches.

In iOS/MacOS there is a system notification that is generated in this exact case. Was wondering if there is something similar that the python runtime can provide.

For reference in Apple GCD -

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatch_source_memory_pressure_event_flags

> var DISPATCH_MEMORYPRESSURE_WARN: Int32 The system memory pressure
>   condition is at the warning stage. Apps should release memory that
>   they do not need right now.

Comment: You mean you want to be notified when your Python process is having trouble allocating memory?  Or you want the actual iOS-specific memory pressure warning which is system-wide?

Comment: I want to know when the system is having memory pressure , lets say 90% memory usage. In that case I want to evict from internal caches etc.